# Width of input type=text element

Tags: html, css, input, width

How come when I do this:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 10px; padding: 2px"/>
<div style="width: 10px; border: solid 1px black; padding: 2px">&nbsp;</div>
```

the input ends up 2 px wider than the div in both IE6 and FF3? What am I missing?

EDIT:
As many people have said, the border is the issue. If I set border: 0px on the input, it will have the same width as the div with a 0 px border (verified by wrapping it inside a bordered SPAN).

However, when I measure the elements in paint, the div has a 14 px interior, just as expected (10+2+2). The input, however, has a 16 px interior, and then a border outside of that. Why is this? Probably not a bug since it happens in both IE6 and FF3, but I dont understand it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe that is just how the browser renders their standard input. If you set a border on the input:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 10px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid black"/>
<div style="width: 10px; border: solid 1px black; padding: 2px"> </div>
```

Then both are the same width, at least in FF.

Comment: Thank you. It appears that it actually is a 2px border, but just visually looks as 1px.

Answer (score 4):

The *visible* width of an element is `width + padding + border + outline`, so it seems that you are forgetting about the border on the input element. That is, to say, that the default border width for an input element on most (some?) browsers is actually calculated as 2px, not one. Hence your input is appearing as 2px wider. Try explicitly setting the `border-width` on the input, or making your div wider.

Comment: Do you mean margin when you say outline, or is outline a new concept that I've never heard of?

Comment: Read about outline here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/outline.html
It says it does not count towards the width of the box, which is true, but it does change the visible width.

Answer (score 0):

input width is 10 + 2 times 1 px for border

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting about the border.  Having a one-pixel-wide border on the Div will *take away* two pixels of total length.  Therefore it will appear as though the div is two pixels shorter than it actually is.

Comment: No! Width + Border = actual width! So the input element is appearing larger.