# Extra padding in <input type="text">

Tags: html, css, padding

It seems that every browser adds some magic hardcoded padding inside `<input type="text">`. Some browsers (IE, Safari, Chrome) make the input box a bit taller, but they properly top align as if it was a regular HTML element. I can live with the extra height. But some browsers misbehave (Firefox and Opera) and also try to either vertically align the text or add some extra padding above it. I'm surprised that modern browsers don't allow to layout textboxes as if they the same way as HTML and add some magic formatting. Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing some trick? Are they some proprietary CSS properties which could help me? I briefly looked at Firefox CSS documentation, but I could not find any. Alternatively, I could use editable HTML instead of `<input type="text">`.

Here is a snippet which demonstrates the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

    <title>Test</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        body, input {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 16pt;
            color: White; }

        #textbox {
            position: absolute;
            left: 20px;
            top: 20px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: #A5C9E2;
            line-height: 16pt;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            border-width: 0px; }

        #box {
            position: absolute;
            left: 120px;
            top: 20px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: #AFD66A;
            line-height: 16pt; }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="textbox" value="Hello">

    <div id="box">Hello</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** I experimented a bit with [-moz-outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/outline) and [-moz-box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing) in Firefox (just in case), but none of their values removes the extra padding.

Comment: Start by closing your input: ....="Hello" />

Comment: Check out the accepted answer to [this question][1] [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143789/width-of-input-typetext-element

Comment: It is indeed valid as he's not using XHTML.

Comment: I believe it is valid in HTML 4.01 Transitional, but surely, it is not the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove the extra, and different pseudo-padding on text inputs in Webkit and Gecko?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981420/how-can-i-remove-the-extra-and-different-pseudo-padding-on-text-inputs-in-webki)

Answer (score 9):

You can eliminate this extra padding by changing the box-sizing of the input.

```
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
```

It makes the modern browsers behave the same. You might need to target IE specifically.

Comment: I'm trying to apply this to `input[type="search"]` and there's still one pixel of "padding" in Firefox that I can't seem to get rid of...

Answer (score 3):

I experimented by changing your line-height and font-size values to 20px and then inspecting the element with Firebug. The clientHeight and offsetHeight properties are both 24px (but since those properties include any padding set on the element I'm not sure if this is the browser expanding the element height, or adding padding).

Explicitly setting the height of the input to be the same as the line-height seems to do what you want, i.e. `line-height: 16pt; height: 16pt;` - but I suspect it works by clipping the element, as the vertical position of the text within the input doesn't change.