# Why do text inputs have extra padding?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I'm trying to overlay text on an `<input type="text">` (for cross-browser `placeholder` support).  I've found that my positioning is always off by a couple of pixels, because of some kind of padding which can't be removed by setting `padding: 0;`.  The suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981420/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846515/) do not solve the problem.

You can see this padding in the following screenshot from Chrome, as the white space between the blue highlight and the yellow border:

[image]

How can I a) remove this space; or b) measure it using Javascript?

Comment: Have you tried a CSS reset?

Comment: You should consider using something like [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) if you don't want to deal with a full CSS reset (which in almost all cases is unnecessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the default borders with your own, the padding goes away (at least for me, on Chrome/Mac):

[image]

This is the CSS I used:

```
input {
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NZZ5B/

Comment: This works for me in Chrome 29.0.1547.57. The reason is that Chrome defaults to a a 2px inset border, which has the effect of looking like a single-pixel, solid border with an extra pixel of spacing

Comment: Fantastic!  This works in the most recent versions of Chrome, Firefox (which was okay to begin with), and Safari, as well as IE8 and 9, but not in Opera and IE10.  Any idea why?

Comment: @1'' Did you reset padding, margin too? And did you try setting the border-box box model?

Comment: My jsfiddle looks ok to me in Opera 15/Mac. I can't test on IE right now. @1''

Comment: Yes, it's fine, I just forgot to reset padding to 0 after all that.  Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You need to reset everything. So it is best recommended to use:

```
<style>
html, body {

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}
</style>
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: This doesn't work, although it's generally a good solution to problems like this.