# Unnecessary margin above input box

Tags: html, css

Working on project and for some mysterious reason I'm getting margin above all my input boxes.

```css
.header {
  height: 100px; width: 100%; 
  background-color: #ef5fc2; 
  position: relative; color: white;
}

.header p {
  position: relative; top: 25px; 
  margin-top: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Itim', cursive; 
  font-size: 40px; 
  margin: 0px; padding: 0px; 
  text-align: center; 
  background-color: pink;
}

body form p {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.container {
  height: 700px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: red; 
  color: white; 
  height: 70px; 
  width: 100%;
}

.footer p {
  font-size: 20px; 
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.footer p:first-child {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.container form p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form input {
  margin-top: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

form {
  position: relative; 
  top: 30px;
}

#submitbtn {
  position: relative; 
  border: 5px solid #ff3385; 
  border-radius: 6px; 
  background-color: #ff3385; 
  padding: 5px 10px; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: white;
}

.submitContainer {
  height: 50px; 
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#agreement {
  font-size: 20px; 
  width: 320px; 
  top: 300px; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 120px; 
  text-align: left;
  border: 2px solid red; 
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Your first name</p>
  <input type="text" name="first name" value="">
  <p>Your last name</p>
  <input type="text" name="last name" value="">
  <p>Your address (inc. zip/post code)</p>
  <input id="userAddress" class="addressBox" type="text" name="address box" value="">
  <p>Your date of birth</p>
  <input type="text" name="date of birth" value="">
  <p>Your email</p>
  <input type="email" name="email" value="">
  <p>Your cell phone number</p>
  <input id="marginBottom" type="number" name="phone number" value=""> 
</form>
```

When I peeked into developer's tools in Chrome and took a closer look at margin and padding highlighting tool in that place where I have extra margin it doesn't show anything useful. It just jumps from the `p` tag straight to `input` tag without acknowledging the unnecessary gap. It does acknowledge the margin above the `p` tags but those don't bug me.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Use a form of reset.css in your stylesheet, or just use `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` at the start, and see if that fixes that problem (it will introduce other problems, but those can be fixed by assigning margin and padding to the elements affected)

Comment: BTW, those `<p>`s you have there should be `<label>`, with a `for=""` containing the ID of the `input` element. Like this: `<label for="first_name">Your first name</label><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">` - you cannot have `name` that contains spaces.

Comment: Try setting the padding and border to 0. Or this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846515/extra-padding-in-input-type-text

Comment: The suggestion from IQtheMC worked ! I set border to none and display to inline-block and worked like a charm !

Comment: Yes .. thanks for the suggestion about <label> tags. Kinda forgotten about them. Sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That gap was caused by the body's `font-size: 40px`, now changed to 16px

I also changed the `p` to `label` and gave them `display: block` so they break line.

Now you can adjust the gaps using margin's on the input's and label's

*As mentioned in a comment, there should be no spaces in the name attributes so I removed them*

```css
.header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ef5fc2;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}
.header p {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Itim', cursive;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: pink;
}
body form label {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
}
.container {
  height: 700px;
}
.footer {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer p {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.footer p:first-child {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.container form a {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
form input {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
form {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}
#submitbtn {
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid #ff3385;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #ff3385;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.submitContainer {
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#agreement {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 320px;
  top: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Your first name</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
  <label>Your last name</label>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
  <label>Your address (inc. zip/post code)</label>
  <input id="userAddress" class="addressBox" type="text" name="addressbox" value="">
  <label>Your date of birth</label>
  <input type="text" name="dateofbirth" value="">
  <label>Your email</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" value="">
  <label>Your cell phone number</label>
  <input id="marginBottom" type="number" name="phonenumber" value="">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to know about margin and spacing in page is using inspect element feature of browser . Just click on the one of the text-box or on the space , it will give respective element which is causing so .

There you can edit it

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant by developer's tools. Didn't show me anything I can work with. That feature normally shows you all margins and padding used and why they are used but this time it just skips the margin without telling me any information about it.